# postgresql inner join duplicating some records

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a large query developed as cte, in certain parts I have to make totals of secondary tables using inner joins to minimize the number of records processed, somehow two subqueries almost identical one works and the second duplicates 8 times some of the totalized records

I need to use inner join or the response time is shoots to the sky by 15x or more times

```
with 
p0 as (select distinct on (pventa) pventa, p.tipo tpva from lecturas l 
     left join puntoventa p on l.pventa=p.numero where dia between '2017-10-01' and '2017-10-31' and p.tipo in ('A','E')),

r1 as (select p.tpva, l.pventa, dia, turno  from lecturas l
       inner join p0 p on p.pventa=l.pventa  
       where dia between '2017-10-01' and '2017-10-31'),

p1 as (select pva, remision, sum(abono), count(abono) from pagosremisiones p
      inner join movsgas m on p.pva=m.pventa and p.remision=m.folio   
      inner join r1 r      on r.pventa=m.pventa and r.dia=m.dia and r.turno=m.turno group by 1,2 order by 1,2 ),

f1 as (select c.serie, c.factura, sum(abono), count(abono) from chequefactura c
      inner join movsgas m on c.serie=m.serie and c.factura=m.factura      
      inner join r1 r      on r.pventa=m.pventa and r.dia=m.dia and r.turno=m.turno  group by 1,2 order by 1,2 )

select * from p1
```

Nprem and ncheck are for debugging

P1 and f1 depend on r1, p1 works (as far as I've tried) without duplicate records (nprem corresponds to existing registers), however, ncheck increases on some records up to 8 times its actual values

I'm not sure if the correct p1's results are purely casual and don't know how to correct duplicates in f1

I do have the alternative of doing direct subqueries but I have a didactic interest in using joins

Btw, so far direct subqueries are much more efficient than the joins possibly because they have been poorly structured

What am I doing wrong?

What would you do to optimize the code?

Thanks in advance

Jose

Comment: That is quite unclear. Can you come up with a simpler query and some sample data that exhibit the problem so it can be reproduced easily?

Comment: I am sorry Lawrewnz, it was quite large for here

Comment: So is the problem/question that the code isn't optomized or that you are getting duplicates? Right now this is just a series of subqueries. If you are getting duplicates, then it suggests that the stuff you are joining is not unique in at least one of the joined tables/subqueries. Without seeing all of your data there is no way for us to diagnose as it's a data issue. Furthermore, as it's written your `f1` CTE is superfluous. Why is it included here? It's very confusing.

Comment: Thanks JNevill. The problem is that I’m getting duplicates in f1, what matters are totals [sum(abono)] in p1 and in f1; inner joins pretend to minimize records processed to totalize fewest chesquefactura records corresponding to r1´s period, I can’t understand why movgas and r1’s inner joins reprocess (duplicate) up to 8 times certain chesquefactura records; p1 so far has no duplicating problems

Answer (score 0):

the trick needed is the new subquery r2 including [ distinct on (serie, factura) ], if I omit it the error persists; duplicates in r2 do not correspond to the number of duplicates in f1, so I had no idea where so many came from; thank you all and again an apology for the terrible description of my problem

```
with
p0 as (select distinct on (pventa) pventa, p.tipo tpva from lecturas l
     left join puntoventa p on l.pventa=p.numero where dia between '2017-10-01' and '2017-10-31' and p.tipo in ('A','E')),

r1 as (select p.tpva, l.pventa, dia, turno  from lecturas l
       inner join p0 p on p.pventa=l.pventa
       where dia between '2017-10-01' and '2017-10-31'),

r2 as (select distinct on (serie, factura)  m.serie,m.factura from movsgas m
      inner join chequefactura c on  c.serie=m.serie and c.factura=m.factura
      inner join r1 r on r.pventa=m.pventa and r.dia=m.dia and r.turno=m.turno),

p1 as (select pva, remision, sum(abono) payp from pagosremisiones p
      inner join movsgas m on p.pva=m.pventa and p.remision=m.folio
      inner join r1 r      on r.pventa=m.pventa and r.dia=m.dia and r.turno=m.turno group by 1,2 order by 1,2 ),

f1 as (select c.serie, c.factura, sum(abono) payfr2, count(*) from chequefactura c
      inner join r2 r      on r.serie=c.serie and r.factura=c.factura  group by 1,2 order by 1,2 )
```